# Java LWJGL glfwGetMonitorPhysicalSize & glfwGetVideoMode not returning expected values

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I'm currently trying to make a basic monitor utility class for getting and printing info on monitors. Im using LWJGL in java for this. When i call the function glfwGetMonitorPhysicalSize, i always get a 0 returned for both x and y. and the glfwGetVideoMode function only returns "- ' ". I can't find what i'm doing wrong here!

Also the monitorID seems to be different each time i run the program. Is this normal?

Note that this code is just a test snippet:

```
private static GLFWErrorCallback errorCallback = Callbacks.errorCallbackPrint(System.out);
private static PointerBuffer monitors = null;

public static long getPrimaryMonitor(){
    glfwSetErrorCallback(errorCallback);

    if(glfwInit() == GL_FALSE)
        System.out.println("error");

    monitors = glfwGetMonitors();
    long monitorId = monitors.get(0);

    // Monitor name
    System.out.println(glfwGetMonitorName(monitorId));

    // Monitor physical size
    IntBuffer xSize = IntBuffer.allocate(4);
    IntBuffer ySize = IntBuffer.allocate(4);
    glfwGetMonitorPhysicalSize(monitorId, xSize, ySize);

    System.out.print("Pos X: ");
    while(xSize.hasRemaining())
        System.out.print(xSize.get());
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Pos Y: ");
    while(ySize.hasRemaining())
        System.out.print(ySize.get());
    System.out.println();

    // Monitor video mode
    ByteBuffer videoMode = glfwGetVideoMode(monitorId);

    System.out.print("Video mode: ");
    while(videoMode.hasRemaining())
        System.out.print(videoMode.getChar());
    System.out.println();

    return monitorId;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution! The functions were actually returning valid value's, but apparently i was reading them the wrong way!

The correct way for video mode:

```
ByteBuffer vidmode = glfwGetVideoMode(monitorId);

System.out.println("Video mode width: " + GLFWvidmode.width(vidmode));
System.out.println("Video mode height: " + GLFWvidmode.height(vidmode));
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably should use `glfwGetPrimaryMonitor()` instead of `glfwGetMonitors().get(0)`.
For what `glfwGetMonitorPhysicalSize` gives you back I only can say I get the same result.
As for documentation it says:

> Returns the size, in millimetres, of the display area of the specified monitor.
>   Any or all of the size arguments may be NULL. If an error occurs, all non-NULL size arguments will be set to zero. Notes: This function may only be called from the main thread. Some systems do not provide accurate monitor size information, either because the EDID data is incorrect, or because the driver does not report it accurately.

So maybe your system just doesn't support it, as well as mine.

And, yes, it's normal that the monitorID is different because its like a pointer and points to dynamically allocated content.

Comment: But I guess every monitor must have a video mode right?

Comment: Yes thats true. For me it outputs 2 random characters.